# Groovy and Grails Tools suite will not run at all

Tags: grails, groovy

I had the GGTS v3.3.0 installed on my Windows XP Pro PC with Java JDK v.1.6_31 and it worked fine.

Since, I've had my PC re-imaged to Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, and the GGTS no longer works.

I have uninstalled and re-installed several times, trying GGTS v3.3.0 and v3.5.0 and every time it gives me no trouble installing, but won't run when I try to execute the installed IDE. I get this error:
    An error has occurred. See the log file C:....\ggts-3.3.0.RELEASE\configuration\473459988766.log

I look in this log and I see the stack trace, and the commonalities:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 0 2014-04-24 11:58:21.713
!MESSAGE Could not parse XML contribution for "org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.infopop//plugin.xml".
Any contributed extensions and extension points will be ignored.
!STACK 0
    org.xml.sax.SAXException: Could not acquire XML parsing service.
 ... 
 ... 
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-04-24 11:58:23.153
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.osgi.service.application.ApplicationException: No application id has been found.
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Please let me know what additional information is needed. Thanks in advance.

~Bill

Answer (score 0):

Check if in sts.ini (or eclipse.ini) you have:
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide

Check if in config.ini you have
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench

I also have STS on Win 7 x64 and it worked fine... don't recall seeing anything similar.

You might want to install Java 7 and try launching your STS 3.5.0 with Java 7.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Thank you. No file at all has ' -product org.springsource.sts.ide' in it. The Config.ini file does have 'eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench' in it. I just upgraded to JDK v1.6_45, which is the latest archived version of Java 6. I don't want to go to Java 7 yet, and since it worked before using Java v1.6_31, I only updated to the later version because I read in the readme file that something about needing v1.6_37 or v7_9. I currently have GGTS v3.3.0 - what I originally had.

Comment: There is the following in GGTS.ini: '-product
org.springsource.ggts.ide'

Comment: Hmm... perhaps it's fine in terms of application id. Maybe it's the invalid plugin.xml that causes GGTS to crash. Can you check the contents of org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.infopop//plugin.xml file in your plugins folder? Meanwhile I'll try installing GGTS on my Win7 pro with Java 6.

Comment: BTW, might be that org.xml.sax is missing from your JDK somehow... or it cannot load it and hence none of the extension points are loaded and everything just crashes. Which Eclipse version is your GGTS for? 4.3? 3.8?

Comment: No such file exists in the pluggins folder: org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.infopop//plugin.xml. There is a org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.infopop_1.0.200.v201004150328.jar file, and inside that there is plugin.xml file `plugin> -<extension point="org.eclipse.help.contexts"> <contexts plugin="org.eclipse.wst.html.ui" file="EditorHtmlContexts.xml"/> <contexts plugin="org.eclipse.wst.html.core" file="EditorHtmlContexts2.xml"/> <contexts plugin="org.eclipse.wst.html.ui" file="HTMLWizContexts.xml"/> </extension> </plugin>`. The org.xml.sax is in the src.zip, and I didn't have a problem with it before.

Comment: The problem seems to be that it cannot acquire the  XML parsing service. Could this be due to not entering the java installation location correctly during setup?

Comment: This PC uses a 64 bit Win7 OS. It used to be a 32 bit Win XP OS. I've been running 32 bit Java on it for a year or so with no problems and continue to do so. The version of GGTS I had been using is 32 bit. Is this the problem? If I want to use the 64 bit version of GGTS I will need to use the 64 bit version of Java. Is this a must? Thank you.